# How to (streaming-) insert many small rows (few bytes per row) into BigQuery cost-efficiently?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with the following properties:

```
Table size: 1.64 TB
Number of rows: 9,883,491,153
```

The data is put there using streaming inserts (in batches of 500 rows each).

From the [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) the costs for these inserts so far should roughly be 86 $.

But in reality, it turns out to be around 482 $.

The explanation is in the [pricing docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data_ingestion_pricing):

> Streaming inserts (`tabledata.insertAll`): $0.010 per 200 MB (You are charged for rows that are successfully inserted. Individual rows are calculated using a 1 KB minimum size.)

So, in the case of my table, each row is just 182 bytes, but I need to pay the full 1024 bytes for each row, resulting in ~ 562 % of the originally (incorrectly) estimated costs.

Is there a canonical (and of course legal) way to improve the situation, i.e., reduce cost? (Something like inserting into a temp table with just one array-of-struct column, to hold multiple rows in a row, and then split-moving regularly into the actual target table?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you these options:

Use BigQuery Storage Write API. You can stream records into BigQuery and they can be available as the ones written in the DB, or batch a process to insert a large number of records to commit in a single operation.

Some advantages are:

- Lower cost because you have 2 TB per month free.
- It supports exactly-once semantics through the use of stream offset.
- If a table schema changes while a client is streaming, BigQuery
  Storage Write notifies the client.

Here is more information about [BigQuery Storage Write](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api).

Another option, you could use Beam/DataFlow to create a batch for streaming into BigQuery and use BigQueryIO with the write method of batch.
You can see more information [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.35.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.Method.html).

Comment: That sounds good, thanks a lot. I'll investigate this path. :)